# Busybox doesn't run console

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, qemu, riscv, busybox

I try to run linux on qemu with RISC-V and run busybox as init process.
Linux is loaded successfully,  but when it run's busybox, it freezes on

```
run_actions(SYSINIT);
```

As result, I see in console

```
[   39.492453] Run /init as init process
```

And then it freezes.
I can't write to console for debug, because console hasn't run yet.

I see, that busybox freeze on parsing inittab on `/dev/console::sysinit:-/bin/ash`.

Comment: Have you read `man inittab(5)`? ABove line seems nonsense from _inittab_ perspective. And what leading `-` means for `/bin/ash`? If you want to have working distribution, try Buildroot.

Comment: This line works on real hardware.

Comment: Also this guide do the same https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~qmn/linux/install.html

Comment: */dev/ **console*** makes no sense to me.

Comment: Why? It works on real hardware.

Comment: Because in Qemu what is your _/dev/console_? Have you provided it? Does Qemu provides a driver for it? Does kernel recognizes it as a console?

Comment: I use uart as stdout for Linux, also I have a driver for uart. printk: `Kernel command line: console=ttyS0,115200n8 debug loglevel=7;console [ttyS0] enabled`