# Qemu. Linux doesn't write in console after init

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, qemu, busybox, inittab

I run Linux on QEMU with emulation whole SOC.
Linux loads successfully. Busybox is init process for Linux. But when Linux run it, there are no any out in console. And it freezes on command `/dev/console::sysinit:-/bin/ash` from inittab file. Also I tried to run `print("Hello world")` program as init process, but result is the same. There are no output in console.

I see all kernel debug output in console. Also I see, that driver for UART is loaded.

Inittab content

```
::sysinit:/bin/busybox --install
::sysinit:/bin/mount -t devtmpfs devtmpfs /dev
::sysinit:/bin/mount -t proc proc /proc
::sysinit:/bin/mount -t sysfs sysfs /sys
::sysinit:/usr/local/bin/kernloglvl 4
::sysinit:/etc/init.d/rc
::sysinit:/bin/mount -t nfs -o vers=3 -o nolock share:/srv/nfs /mnt/share
/dev/console::sysinit:-/bin/ash
::shutdown:/bin/umount -a -r
```

Comment: What's your qemu command line?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand the question

Comment: How do yo run qemu?

Comment: qemu-system-riscv64 -nographic -machine $(MACHINE) -s -S  -drive file=$(SD_CARD_IMAGE),if=mtd,format=raw  -bios $(ELF)  -d guest_errors,unimp -smp 1 -m size=1G

Comment: There are multiple questions in your question. First about no console output. Add "-serial stdio" to your command line. Second about freeze of inittab commands. Please add it's contents to your question, so I can see what runlevels are used.

Comment: Whe I add ""-serial stdio", qemu says: "qemu-system-riscv64: -serial stdio: cannot use stdio by multiple character devices". Also I see kernel output in console. I don't see only init process output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228838/discussion-between---and-nevilad).

Comment: @0andriy you posted a link to the same question. Typo?

Comment: This one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66204856/busybox-doesnt-run-console, thanks, @nevilad.